# Saving Kegged Beer For Later

Tags: carbonation, keg, ipa

Kegged my beer, but need it to stay carbonated without using it for a week.  I already carbonated the beer and drank some.  Then, a few days later, I put about 20 lbs of pressure into the keg and shut off the C02 - will this keep the beer fresh and carbonated?  PS - It is a really hoppy IPA.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Commercial kegs in distribution, either in transit or in waiting to be put on tap in bar are … exactly the situation you describe. It will be just fine. You don't really need to add any additional headspace pressure over the pressure to reach you intended carbonation level. Hop flavors fade over time, of course, but that's unrelated to your question.

Comment: thanks...hops fade, that's what they do, I just don't want the beer to go bad.  Thanks for putting into perspective with the commercial kegs.

Answer (score 1):

I have been traveling a lot for the last year and haven't been home to drink much of my beer, so I have been doing this without any serious issue. I didn't add quite so much extra pressure when I was disconnecting the CO2, but I wouldn't expect that to cause problems.

In my experience it does not keep it especially fresh. Right now in my keg I've got a nice spring ale, that was definitely better when it was fresh a couple months ago. That was a recipe that I knew was going to be better fresh, and it's still quite drinkable -I expect to finish it this weekend. I don't know if it would age more or less than in a bottle, but don't expect it to be in perfect stasis while you leave it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am only saving it for a week or two so I am just trying to keep it from going flat and get off flavors in that time.